# How can I get the system configuration with c++ in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I want system configuration like the cpu or graphic card model.

Comment: Hi, did you get your answer or something is missing? If you got, please select an answer, if not, please clarify what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

[QSysInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsysinfo.html) was meant for this purpose.

For example, you can get the CPU architecture using [currentCpuArchitecture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsysinfo.html#currentCpuArchitecture).

Qt uses OpenGL for the rendering, so there is no need for specific API in there as you can use the standard OpenGL API for that:

```
glGetString(GL_VENDOR);
glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
```

For network information, you can use [QNetworkInformation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkinformation.html).

For store information, you can use [QStorageInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstorageinfo.html).

For serial port information (I actually developed this one), you can use [QSerialPortInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qserialportinfo.html).

For printer information, you can use [QPrinterInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprinterinfo.html).

For bluetooth information, you can use [QBluetoothDeviceInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbluetoothdeviceinfo.html).

For  can bus device information, you can use [QCanBusDeviceInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcanbusdeviceinfo.html).

A good hint is to search for "info" classes in [all Qt classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/classes.html).

Qt has consistently named the classes so during its development.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the architecture of cpu, I want the model some thing like "Core i7 9750h", Can you help me with this one?

Comment: There is no really anything ike that in Qt built-in. You will have to do that yourself. Should be easy with QSettings to read the registry and also to run processes with QProcess to obtain it.